# How to reset MultiIndex?

Tags: python, pandas

This is my `df`:

```
id  val1    val2    cnt
1       5       6       1
2       2       5       2
2       5       1       1
3       4       2       1
3       1       3       2
```

I run this code and get MultiIndex:

```
df = df.pivot(index="id", 
              columns="cnt", 
              values=["val1","val2"]) \
       .fillna(0)
```

If I add `.reset_index(level=["id"])`, then I get columnswith `(`, e.g. `('id', '')`.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If need flatten `MultiIndex` in columns use `f-string`s in list comprehension:

```
df = df.pivot(index="id", 
              columns="cnt", 
              values=["val1","val2"]) \
       .fillna(0)

df.columns = [f'{a}_{b}' for a, b in df.columns]

df = df.reset_index()
print (df)
   id  val1_1  val1_2  val2_1  val2_2
0   1     5.0     0.0     6.0     0.0
1   2     5.0     2.0     1.0     5.0
2   3     4.0     1.0     2.0     3.0
```

Another solution:

```
df.columns = ['_'.join(str(y) for y in x) for x in df.columns]
df = df.reset_index()
print (df)
   id  val1_1  val1_2  val2_1  val2_2
0   1     5.0     0.0     6.0     0.0
1   2     5.0     2.0     1.0     5.0
2   3     4.0     1.0     2.0     3.0
```

Comment: Thanks. Does `f'{a}_{b}'` assume that I have 2 columns `val1` and `val2`? Can it be more flexible?

Comment: @Fluxy - then is possible use `df.columns = ['_'.join(str(y) for y in x) for x in df.columns]`

Answer (score 1):

```
df.columns=['_'.join(map(str,i)) for i in df.columns]
```

**output**

```
   val1_1   val1_2  val2_1  val2_2
id              
1   5.0     0.0     6.0     0.0
2   5.0     2.0     1.0     5.0
3   4.0     1.0     2.0     3.0
```